# $E$ is nowhere dense if and only if for each open $O \subseteq E$, the set $E\cap O$ is not dense in $O$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

In a metric space show that subset E is nowhere dense if and only if for each open $O \subseteq E$, the set $E\cap O$ is not dense in $O$.

In order to prove converse part of this statement, I've tried in following way :

$E\cap O$ not dense in $O$ implies that $\text{int}(E\cap O) = \emptyset$, it means we can choose open balls $B(x_i,r_{x,i}) \subset E\cap O$  such that it doesn't contain any element of $E\cap O$. Choose $\epsilon = \min\{r_{x,i}\}$. Therefore $\rho(x_m,x_n) \geq \epsilon$  for any $x_m, x_n \in E\cap O$.  thus there do not exist any sequence which converge to a limit point, thus there do not exist any limit point in $E\cap O$. Therefore $\overline{E\cap O} = E\cap O$. And since $E\cap O$ is not dense in $O \subset E$ therefore $\overline{E\cap O}$ is also not dense in $0\subset X$ which implies $\overline{E\cap O}$ is not dense (hollow) in X, therefore according to the definition E is nowhere dense.

Is the above proof enough?

Comment: You mean "for each *non-empty* open subset $O$ of $X$".

Comment: Please include your definition of "nowhere dense" in the question, to make the question more self-contained.

Comment: yes its for non-empty open subset

Comment: subset E of metric space X is Nowhere dense provided its closure is hollow.

Comment: Please edit the question to include this definition. Also, what is the definition of "hollow"?

Comment: Subset is said to be hollow if it's interior is empty

Comment: @UddeshyaKumarSharma: If $E$ is nowhere dense and $O\subset E$ is open, then $O=\emptyset$.

Comment: @AdamRubinson: From the tags (general-topology, for example) it is implicit that there is no need to define the concept of nowhere dense since it is a standard part of the point-set curriculum.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not correct. $E\cap O$ not dense in $O$ does not imply $\mathrm{int}(E\cap O)=\emptyset$. Counter example: $O=(0,1),\, E=(0, 0.5)$. Clearly $E$ is not dense in $O$, but the interior of $E$ is $E$, which is not empty.
Also a ball in $B\cap E$ that does not contain elements fo $B\cap E$ does not make any sense.

Have you thougt about trying the elegant way of contraposition? $E$ is nowhere dense means that $\bar{E}$ has no inner points. What is the negation of this statement? Can you then find an open set $O$ so that $E\cap O$ is dense in $O$?

Comment: Contradiction of nowhere dense subset is not E closure being dense in X.... So what negation should I use?

Comment: @UddeshyaKumarSharma $E$ is nowhere dense means by definition that the interior of the closure of $E$ is empty. The negation of that would be $\bar E$ has an inner point. What does having an inner point mean?